# Eloquent filter products through belongTo by morph model

Tags: laravel, pivot, relationship

**I need to filter Products by pivot table through belongsTo relationship**

model Product

```
        'name',
        'base_unit',
    ];

    public function baseUnit()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsTo(Unit::class, 'base_unit', 'id');
    }
```

model Unit

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function units()
    {
        return $this
            ->morphedByMany(Unit::class, 'unitable')
            ->withPivot('multiplier', 'product_id', 'main');
    }
```

I need to get only products where units.pivot.main=1

I tried

```
        $products = Product::whereHas('baseUnit', function ($q) {
            $q->whereHasMorph(
                'units',
                [User::class],
                function ($qu) {
                    $qu->wherePivot('main', 1);
                });
        })->with('baseUnit.units')
            ->get();
```

and got error

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::getBelongsToRelation() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany given, called in C:\OpenServer\domains\vi-production\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Concerns\QueriesRelationships.php on line 221 and defined in C:\OpenServer\domains\vi-production\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Concerns\QueriesRelationships.php on line 243